# Do applications update without meta packages?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, dpkg

I would like to know if packages will still get updated in Ubuntu if I remove the meta package that owned it.

for example, I would like to remove the hexchat from Ubuntu mate, but it also gets the ubuntu-mate-meta package removed, do other packaged under ubuntu-mate-meta still get updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any package installed with a distribution's package manager will continue to receive updates (assuming updates are made available), regardless of how it was installed. So in your case, all the packages pulled in by `ubuntu-mate-meta` will continue to receive updates, even if you remove `ubuntu-mate-meta`.

Note that you'll probably need to mark all those packages as "non-automatically installed", using `aptitude` (the <kbd>m</kbd> key) or `apt-mark manual`, if you want to avoid them being removed next time you run `apt-get auto-remove` or something similar.

Incidentally, `ubuntu-mate-meta` *wasn't* removed because the package manager reckoned it was unused; it was removed because it depends on `hexchat`, so it can't remain installed if `hexchat` is removed — if you tell the package manager to remove `hexchat`, it assumes you really want that and will remove `ubuntu-mate-meta` (after asking for confirmation).

Answer (score 1):

The reason meta packages mention updates, is for the `dist-upgrade` situation, where *new* packages are added as dependencies, and old packages removed from the repo (or must be removed due to conflicts).

Typically this would occur on upgrade to a new version of ubuntu (e.g. 16.04 -> 16.10).  It is much less common while updating ubuntu within the same version.  Within a version of ubuntu, it is particularly unlikely to occur for a metapackage only.

For example, with Debian, the iceweasel package was replaced with firefox.  (No further security updates to iceweasel were released).  But the replacement and update still would occur, independent of whether or not iceweasel had been installed by a metapackage for a desktop environment.